# If I call a function in while loop of a bash script, that function can't have "break" or "continue" on its own?

Tags: bash

For example, say I have this script -

```
cat pr_approvals.txt | while read -r approval; do
    # CHECKING IF PR IS NOT APPROVED YET.
    if [ "$approval" == "" ]; then
        echo "No approval found." 
    else
        approved_id=`echo $approval | cut -d ' ' -f1`
        approver=`echo $approval | cut -d ' ' -f2`
        check_approval
        echo "Last code commit in $3 PR #$1 is approved by @$approver. Proceed. " 
    fi
done


check_approval () {
    allowed_approvers="abc,def,ghi"
    if [[ ! ",$allowed_approvers," =~ ",$approver," ]]; then
        echo "@$approver is not in $team_of_approvers team. Approval not enough for merge. "
        continue
    else
        if [[ $repo_fullname == "sfdc" ]]; then
            if [[ ! "$approved_id" == "1111"* ]]; then
                echo "@$approver's approval is not valid."
                continue
            else
                echo "@$approver's approval is valid."
            fi
        fi
    fi
}
```

This is not my exact or full script. Actual script has way more code and complexity. But I reduced it to this to demonstrate my issue.

I'm calling the `check_approval` function from within the while loop of the main script. The `check_approval` function itself doesn't have any while loop in it, but since it is running within the while loop of the main script, I thought the "continue" code will affect that loop when it comes to that.

Apparently not. My script is failing with this error -

```
continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Is there any way to affect the while loop of the main script via a function called within that while loop, when the function itself doesn't have a while loop?

[Keep in mind that I can't add a while loop in this function.]

Comment: The error is a good indicator that you need to refactor your code

Comment: Start from https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `check_approval || continue` - just make sure you return an error code where you want the `continue`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @PaulHodges. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, modify your function to take arguments and return a proper value indicating whether the check succeeds

```
check_approval () {
    local -r approved_id="$1"
    local -r approver="$2"
    
    # check whatever you want
    # return the proper value
    [[ "$valid" == true ]]
}


...


while [[ whatever ]]; do
    ...
    if check_approval "$approved_id" "$approver"; then
        echo "Last code commit in $3 PR #$1 is approved by @$approver. Proceed. "
    else
        echo "ERROR" >&2
    fi
done
```